# why can't my java code read the condition?

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, conditional-statements

what I attend to do is when the array(from 0 to n-1) is given, to sum the array values with the index minus multiple of 3 start from the end.
for example, when 7 arrays are given, I want to sum a[0] a[2] a[3] a[5] a[6].

below is error part of the code I programmed.

```
        int j = 0;

        for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
                j = i*3;

                if(i!=n-j)
                        r += array[i];
        }
```

my code can't read the condition and just sum all the array values.
I don't know why. can someone help me ?

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code with a debugger, in order to check the state of your program at each point in time, as well as your assumptions about its behavior?

Comment: The code can "read the condition" just fine. The issue is that the condition is never false.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and edit your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also, check [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jdb.html) out.

Comment: Someone suggested the use of a debugger but an easier alternative is to insert the following line just before the `if` and observe what's happening: `System.out.println("i: " + i + " j: " + j + " n: " + n + " n-j: " + (n-j) + " r: " + r);` -- are those values what you'd expect them to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's debug!

first time through the loop:

`i = 0`
`j = i * 3` soo... `0`
if (0 != 7 - 0) ... - it's not, of course, so `i = 0` qualifies and is added.

next loop:

`i = 1`
`j = 3`

if (1 != 7 - 3)  ... - it's not, of course, so `i = 1` qualifies and is added.

Which you did not want.

Given that this is homework, this should be enough for you to take another step and figure out what you SHOULD be doing here. I will give some tips:

You can loop, counting backwards, just as well. You'd have to use `i--` of course (decrement i by 1 every time), and you'd use `int i = n` or perhaps `int i = n - 1` as initializing expression in your for loop.

That whole 'is it a 3rd factor from the top' part cannot be calculated using `i` at all, you'd need something separate for this. You can declare variables outside (you already did that, `int j = 0`, but you're not looking for 0 so much as 'the first index from the top I do not want'. Then you can use `if` to check if it is that index. If so, you don't want to add that number to your sum AND you want to update your `j`.

Answer (score 1):

For tasks like that the modulo operator is usually your friend.
I tried it like this and it works:

```
    int r = 0;
    int[] array = new int[7];

    for(int i = array.length; i >= 0; i--){
        int numberOfIteration = array.length - i;
        if(numberOfIteration % 3 > 0){
            System.out.println("Add array[" + i + "]");
            r += array[i];
        }
    }
```